# Count how many times a user logs in with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm using flask_login to authenticate my users logging in. ***I'd like to count every time they successfully log into my app.***

Here's what my log in route looks like:

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    # Bypass if user is logged in
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    # continue
    form = LoginForm(request.form)

    # Validate login attempt
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # Get data
        my_data = {k:v for k,v in form.allFields.data.items()}

        # If the user is in the db
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=my_data["email"]).first()

        if user and user.check_password(password=my_data["password"]):

            # This is where the user is logged in  <----------------------- !
            login_user(user,remember=True)

        # Otherwise
        flash('Invalid username/password combination')
        return redirect(url_for('/login'))
    return render_template(
        'login/login.html',
        form=form,
        title='Log in.',
        template='login-page'
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model `UserLoginCount` with the field `user_id` and `count`. After `login_user(user,remember=True)` do the following,

- Insert new row if it is the first log in of a user.
- After the first log in, increment `count` column for each successful log in.

Insert this code after `login_user(user,remember=True)`.

```
obj = UserLoginCount.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id).first()
if obj:
    obj.count = obj.count + 1
else:
    obj = UserLoginCount(user_id=user.id, count=1)

dbsession.add(obj)   
dbsession.flush()
```

Note: This is basic implementation. Using foreign key will be best approach. [You can look here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html).

Comment: How would the latter be executed?

Comment: Check if there is any entry with this user or not. If there exist an entry get it and update count column. If no entry found insert one with count = 1.

Comment: Can you demonstrate code-wise how that would be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `login_count` property added to your User class, or a separate model that ties each User to their `login_count`.  Then, increment the count each time they log in.

Show your `User` model with `UserMixin` if you need help setting that up

Comment: How do I do the latter of this? _"increment the count each time they log in"_